# What could explain that a USB cable starts charging my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone after ~2 secs, but takes over 5 min to start charging my Pixel 6 phone?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-9, google-pixel-6

I have a male-to-male, USB-A-to-USB-C cable. It starts charging my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone after ~2 secs, but takes over 5 min to start charging my Pixel 6 phone. What could explain that?

I have no information on the cable as nothing is written on it. I tried different chargers: the cable charges my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone but never on my Google Pixel 6 phone. My other male-to-male, USB-A-to-USB-C cables charge my Google Pixel 6 phone just fine (i.e., within a few seconds after getting plugged).

Samsung Galaxy S9 charging:

> [image]

Google Pixel 6 not charging:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: What indicator do you use to see that your Pixel is charging?

Comment: @Robert battery icon is at the top right of the screen, next to the percent of much it is charged. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNkj1.png

Comment: As that icon is updated by Android itself it should be correct. Excluding a hardware problem the only thing that comes to my mind is that Pixel phones differentiate between power connected and charging. So if the phone is connected to the charger but consumes more power than the charger provides the battery is still discharging. But I don't know if the icon is showing charging or power connected state.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I consider it as cable dependant. charger wattage of pixel 6 is 30W and that of S9 is 15W. May be that cable supports fast charging up to 15W only. I also had similar experience with my moto. It accepts fast charging, only when moto charger and cable connected, otherwise shows slow charging.

Comment: Not sure if related, but I have a similar experience on Pixel 3a until now when charging through a power bank. When I directly plug the USB A-to-C cable from a power bank to Pixel 3a, it won't charge. But if I charge the power bank for a moment so that it's powered on then plug the USB A-to-C to Pixel 3a, then it will eventually charge (although slowly).

Comment: guess the Pixel is confused with USB-PD mode because it detects "some device" (on USB-A side)